# adding a global dictionary to an AppDelegate vs singleton class

Tags: iphone, ios

I see it is recommended that global data (ie an NSArray or NSDictionary) be defined in a singleton class rather than the AppDelegate.

Why is this?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Where do you see that recommendation?

Comment: not an official recommendation, just threads on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

The AppDelegate is specific to the project you are working on. If you decide to start a fresh version of the app you are working on or (more likely) to port it to Mac from iOS etc...

The the AppDelegate will stay where it is.

By putting global information like that into a singleton you create a class that is independent of the app it is being run in.

Also, you're best off keep App specific stuff (like applicationWillEnterBackground) in the AppDelegate and don't want to clog it up with other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to create unit tests for your code, you should avoid global singletons as they make you code more difficult to test. Similarly, having a exposed `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` for these sort of values is, in my experience, code that can easily get buggy quickly.

A design pattern I've found useful is to actually make a  configuration or global-values object with all the properties you want there. Typically this class wraps the `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, which you could load from a plist file. This object can be instantiated in the AppDelegate, then passed around when you instantiate view controllers and other objects. This is more testable because you can easily mock the config object in tests.

An example of how this sort of config object might look when being loaded from a plist file:

The interface:

```
@interface ConfigManager : NSObject {

}
@property (readonly) NSString* masterUser;
@property (readonly) UIImage* masterUserImage;

@end
```

Then in the .m

```
@interface ConfigManager ()
@property (strong) NSDictionary* configDict;

@end

@implementation ConfigManager


-(id)init {

    self = [super init];

    if ( self ) {
        NSString *pathStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AppConfig" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathStr];
        NSString *error = nil;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;

        self.configDict = (NSDictionary*)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];

        if(nil == self.configDict || nil != error ) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);

            return nil;
        }   

    }

    return self;
}

-(NSString*)masterUser {
    return [self.configDict objectForKey:@"masterUser"];
}

-(UIImage*)masterUserImage {
    NSString* imageName = [self.configDict objectForKey:@"masterUserImage"];

    return [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```

Of course, alter the object's properties to suit your needs. The great thing about this approach is that you can implement once the common code needed to process your app's globals config, like loading images. This helps prevent a common class of bugs caused by replicating the same code over and over again through out your code base.

Answer (score 0):

So that you don't clutter up the AppDelegate.  Most AppDelegates are like a kitchen sink of global data.  Everything gets thrown in there.  Using a singleton (or just a regular class if ARC) separates your real global data from basic AppDelegate functions.

Answer (score 0):

I  dont think that Singeltons are a good solution, I prefer that application globals are better kept on a honest global accessible class, like AppDelegate.

18 years ago, a singleton construct were thought to be a design pattern, but later Erich Gamma realized, that it was a bad idea to add that pattern into his book "Design Patterns – Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software".

Today in modern languages like java Singeltons are evil, because you cannot remove them once they are initialized, thus heavily disturbing unit tests. So at least in java its more likely to have a bad design when using singletons. Better be honest, if you have a global object, then handle it as such, and do not hide it behind a pseudo global element.

However Objective-C does not have a Virtual Machine, therefore probably Singletons does not affect unit tests, (I am not sure about this).
If they do not affect Unit test, Singletons sometimes are handy to use, like [NSFileManager defaultManager].
But i would not store a NSArray or Dictionary into a singleton.